# OpenCL kernel arguments

Tags: java, struct, opencl, lwjgl

I've just started fiddling around with OpenCL and I've come across a problem: I do not know how to pass complex data structures as arguments. I'm using LWJGL's OpenCL binding, and the example provided in the wiki http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Sum_Example. In that example 2 float buffers are created and passed as arguments (LWGJL provides methods in a class named [BufferUtils](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.html) for creating these buffers).

Now, how would I create a buffer of points, `typedef struct {int x, int y} tpoint`, or structs in general? There are no structs in Java. Moreover there is no BufferUtils.createStructBuffer method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and writing OpenCL structs on the host can be non-trivial.  Their in-memory layout can depend on the OpenCL device's architecture, and their endianness is not necessarily the host's.

You can control the layout by using the `packed` attribute.  If you use `packed`, this specifies exactly the layout of the struct's members, as opposed to the default which will align the members depending on the OpenCL device's architecture.  Note, however, that with `packed` you may lose performance.

Alternatively, you can also 'ask' the OpenCL device for the struct layout with a small kernel:

```
kernel void struct_layout(global unsigned long* totalSize, global unsigned long* fieldOffsets)
{
    tpoint theStruct;
    totalSize[0] = sizeof(theStruct);
    unsigned long baseOffset = (unsigned long)&theStruct;
    fieldOffsets[0] = (unsigned long)&theStruct.x - baseOffset;
    fieldOffsets[1] = (unsigned long)&theStruct.y - baseOffset;
}
```

For your particular case, If you packed the tpoint struct then from Java you could just use a byte buffer and read/write ints to it and alternate between the `x` and `y` members of each struct value.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ...;

int x1, y1 = ...;
int x2, y2 = ...;

buf.putInt(x1).putInt(y1);
buf.putInt(x2).putInt(y2);
```