# Passing structs containing size_t from Java to OpenCL

Tags: java, struct, opencl, lwjgl

One of the arguments for `CL12.clCreateImage()` is a `ByteBuffer` containing this [struct](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/imageDescriptor.html). I will be using the method described in [OpenCL kernel arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778070/opencl-kernel-arguments) to pass the struct but am not certain what to use for the arguments that are of type `size_t`. From Java,when I put the arguments into the `ByteBuffer`, should  I use an `int` (signed 32 bit) if I am using a 32-bit system or a `long` (signed 64 bits) if I am using a 64-bit?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

a size_t type is an "unsigned int". You can definitely use int type but make sure it is not a negative number, otherwise it makes no sense.

When considering the above, You should not worry about 32 and 64 bit systems and you should not need to use a long

so you can do something like

```
int param = value; //this is the value to pass
if (param >= 0) {
  pclFunc((size_t)param)
} else {
  //see how you want to handle this
}
```

Comment: Are you sure size_t is always 32bits ? AFAIK size_t is the same size as int and then could be 0 to 2^64 - 1 on a 64bits system.

Comment: apologies, size_t is always unsigned int size, regardless which size the int is

Comment: How do I determine the size of an unsigned int?

Comment: usigned int has the exact same size as a signed int.they only differ in range. so unsgned int in 32 bit system has range 0-2^32, while in singed system has the range -2^31-2^31, because 1 bit is reserved for the +- sign

Comment: I'm not close to my work pc now, but I bet u that size_t is defined as: "typedef usigned int size_t"